# Coast 3-way -- does this conform with Code?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, code-compliance, nec

For those who aren't familiar, the California or Coast 3-way switching arrangement  is a method of wiring a three-way switch circuit that is used when both a switched and an unswitched hot are desired at both ends of the circuit, as seen in this image (taken from the Wikipedia page on three-way switches):

[image: Coast/California three-way wiring]
However, it requires *two* travelers, a hot, a neutral, and an EGC all in the same cable -- and 12/4 or 14/4 NM is a recent invention, as I understand it.  Has 14/4 been around for longer than I think, or were Coast three-ways installed with 14/3 and a separate (or no) neutral running with the travelers?  If the latter is true, wouldn't they violate 300.3(B) (and a few other Code sections) due to the wayward neutral conductor?

Comment: I'd guess that before x/4 cable, you'd use two x/2 cables.  The grounded (neutral) would be grouped with the ungrounded (hot), and the travellers would be in the other cable. Or you could run four wires through conduit.

Comment: Pretty common in older California homes to see no neutral wire in switch boxes or running with the switched hots, neutral at the load only.

Comment: If you're using x/4 or 2 x/2 cables, why bother? Just wire the 3-ways normally, and run two travelers and hot and neutral. Much less confusing to anyone trying to decipher the wiring later, and you only need to pigtail one connector instead of two (eg: http://i.imgur.com/pDQAXfi.png). However, the question remains: if done in way that saves a conductor (by using a neutral from somewhere else for the light), does that meet code? It would be interesting to see some real examples of where this is actually useful (I have never seen this in the real world, but I'm on the East coast..).

Comment: @JimmyFix-it -- that might actually be the answer, come to think of it!

Comment: The requirement for the neutral is a newer code requirement, if your home was built prior to the 2014 code being adopted it was not a requirement to have the neutral at the switch box.

Comment: The circuit above is advantageous in cases where one needs to have a switched load near the left switch as well as the right switch, and a full-time hot wire available near the right switch, as might be desirable with e.g. a porch and a detached garage.  Accommodating such requirements with a conventional three-way arrangement would require running five wires between the porch and the garage: hot, neutral, two travelers, and a switched return.  The scheme above would allow that to be done using four wires from porch to garage.

Comment: @supercat -- yeah, I understand the tradeoff (having switched-hot + always-hot at both ends without exceeding the size of available cables vs. being restricted to two switches in the arrangement) -- I'm just not sure how long /4 cable's been a thing!

Comment: The need to run 4 wires plus ground has been around a long time, though it might have been satisfied by running multiple cables next to each other.  Personally, I dislike the use of the circuit above in cases where there's no load near the left-side switch.  Someone looking in the first box who wants to move the remote outlet to a circuit separate from the light might reasonably think the way to do that by separating lower black wire between the boxes and connecting it to a new circuit, while leaving the switch connection on the old one, but that would be dangerous.

Comment: Although things would appear to work as they should after the change, and even the breakers would work as they should when either switch is in the up position, having both switches in the down position would cause everything on either circuit to be fed from both.

Comment: @supercat that's definitely a legit concern

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I could be wrong on this but when I worked as an electrician in California many years ago, the coast 3 way switching was developed for the following reason. Many homes and offices were wired using steel flex (aluminum came later). Most cities in California at that time had their own electrical code, governed to some degree by the state code and NEC. There were some rules that did not allow you to pull four wires (Conductors) in a 1/2" flex conduit unless one was a switch leg.

By using a coast 3 way the conductors were as follows: one point wire (Common) one switch leg, one Hot and one neutral, with no travelers. Plus of course if you needed a hot plus a switch leg and a neutral at each end, you would have them available. On a standard 3 way switching you would have two travelers (In the UK these are called Strapping wires).

Answer (score 0):

I have heard of a borrowed neutral from another circuit, I doubt it would kill someone but imagine a guy on a ladder, he shut the power off for the circuit he was wrkg on and maybe gets a 'bite of some current possibly quite surprised loses balance and falls off the ladder. I saw a service panel, 12 fuses to 6 circuits, the other 6 fuses were on the neutral side, it was all K&T. I was hooking up a recep in the kitchen of an old house, I unscrewed the fuse and the lamp went out, due to being on a fused neutral. my leg touched the cast iron radiator and like where the hell did that come from?, I put my wiggy on the radiator and the wire I was working on, a full 110 volts, always a FUN time with knob' n tube.

Comment: This doesn't address the question asked -- I've heard tales of borrowed neutral shenans in K&T myself, but you're not making any connection between your tale and Coast/California 3-ways

Answer (score -1):

Having a line, switched line, and neutral at each end of a  particular switched set of lumenaires is effective when an installer has separated the perm fixed lighting on it's own branch circuit when visibility/safety are criteria in the design due to the possibility of breakers tripping open as a consequence of several variable factors such as required GFCI devices, 80% rated small appliances, etc.  I find the incurred cost of 30-40 addn. ft. of 12 or 14/2 nm-b respectively is well worth it compared to the time and labor of installing additional circuits to provide lighting redundancy in the prev mentioned examples.  The capability to go from one room to next is also of importance when replacing or installing fixed lumenaires in bedrooms that are already closed-in such as a finished attic(1.5 story).   As 4 borrowing another circuits neutral, by rule probably not allowed. Depending on the size of the lighting load, could be trouble, but with light emitting diodes these days, 40 to 60 additional volt amperes on a "barrowed neutral" isn't gonna burn the place down.....